# how to bind recentf-mode to C-u C-r

Tags: key-bindings

When I try to do that it is given me the prefix error. Can someone tell me how to still achieve this please? Using both bind-key and bind-keys* did not work for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`C-u C-r` will pass a prefix argument to the function `isearch-backward` which is already bound to `C-r`.  If you insist on doing that, this might help:

```lisp
(global-unset-key [?\C-r])
(global-set-key [?\C-r] 
                #'(lambda (prefix-arg)
                    (interactive "p")
                    (cond
                     ((eq prefix-arg 1)
                      (isearch-backward))
                     ((eq prefix-arg 4)
                      (recentf-mode 'toggle)))))
```

---

1. Unset the original key binding.
2. Bind the key `C-r` to a new lambda function.
3. _

   1. If the lambda function doesn’t detect a prefix argument, it will invoke `isearch-backward` which is originally bound to `C-r`;
   2. else (if you type `C-u`), it will **call `recentf-mode` with an argument `'toggle`**.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll probably need a dedicated package like [mykie](https://github.com/yuutayamada/mykie-el) to overwrite reserved prefix C-u.

According to the original guidance, it will be like this:

```lisp
(require 'mykie)
(setq mykie:use-major-mode-key-override t)
(mykie:initialize)
(mykie:set-keys global-map
  "C-r"
  :default isearch-backward ;; found in global-map
  :C-u recentf-open-files ;; any command you want to map to "C-u C-r"
  )
```